# Changing field order dynamically in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my project I made many changes in database and at some time I need to re-assign order to some table in my database. so, I want is. I have following table.

```
id     name     address     order
1      vijay    mumbai      2
3      ram      delhi       4
4      ravi     pune        5
5      rutul    surat       8
9      vipul    agra        11
```

And I want to update it from mysql query...like

```
id     name     address     order
1      vijay    mumbai      0
3      ram      delhi       1
4      ravi     pune        2
5      rutul    surat       3
9      vipul    agra        4
```

So I want is my order field to update from 0 to plus one and on and on...
How to do that I have no idea...I try but I am also not near to the solution. How to do that? Please help me.

Comment: you can try using row number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
SET @orderid = -1;    
update yourTableName set `order` = (@orderid:=@orderid+1)
order by id asc
```

**EDIT:**

In codeIgniter you can do like following:

```
$this->db->query("SET @orderid = -1");
$this->db->query("update table_name set `order` = (@orderid:=@orderid+1) order by id asc");
```

Comment: Of course using `order` in a query will make mysql cough :-) Using `\`order\`` would be better....

Comment: Yup, Also advisable to avoid column name of **mysql** default key words

Comment: Yup, it's working...do you have any idea how to implement it on codeigniter function?

Comment: or else how can i call that query from php?

Comment: how can i do this in laravel?